# MVC (Not Using Razor) - How to remove scripts files in master page to ascx control and use them

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have MVC app using traditional aspx views not Razor. I have a bunch of  blocks of js files references in Master file. I ideally want to move them somewhere else so I can just reference them will just one line in the master file. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Create a partial view (I will call mine MyPartialViewWithScripts) and place it in your shared directory.  In this partial view, list out all of the javascript files that you need/want to display in the master layout.  Then in your master layout call

**Partial View**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathToJSfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PathToJSfile2.js"></script>
```

**Master Layout**

```
<html><head>
<% Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialViewWithScripts")%>
</head>
```